# run mysql:5.5 docker image from ansible

Tags: mysql, docker, ansible

How to run mysql: 5.5 from ansible? If I run it directly:

```
docker run -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass mysql:5.5
```

it's work ok. But if I run from ansible:

```
- name: run database
  local_action:
    module: docker
    image: mysql:5.5
    state: running
```

it's start and immediately stop. Also post in case 1 is 3306/tcp, but in case 2 there is no port.

Comment: `find / -name '*log*' -exec grep -il 'err' {} \+`

Comment: How is this link with ansible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify mysql root password as environment variable for container. For example:

---

```
- hosts: ansible_host
  gather_facts: False
  sudo: yes
  pre_tasks:
    - name: install pip pkg.
      yum:
        name: python-pip
        state: present

    - name: install boto pkg.
      pip:
        name: docker-py
        state: present

    - name: docker
      docker:
        image: "mysql:5.5"
        state: running
        env: "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw"
```